Adding external users to Azure DevOps git repository and deny in multiple repositories isn't working
I have gone through so many blogs and none of them were helpful for my use case. I have a few external users and I added them all in a Permission group and denied "Read" permissions all of them in security section.
Then I went to the repo where I want to add the group and gave the necessary permissions (read, contribute, create branch, etc)
The good thing is, I get "You dont have access" to all the repositories, but along with the repo where I need access.
Tried everything, inheritance permissions, removed the group and gave individual access, nothing worked.
Please can someone help me or at least help me know if there is a solution for this?

Honestly, none of these answers work, I tried so many things.
So, after 1237 tries, it worked.

The external User already had Basic (nothing changed here)
Make sure this is set- Go to Project Settings --> Permissions --> (Group you created) --> Permissions Tab --> ALLOW "View Project-level information"
Go to Repositories --> Security section, remove that permission group.
Now go to the intended repo where you want to grant access --> Add that group and ALLOW necessary permissions(Read, Contribute, Contribute to Pull requests, etc)

This is all I did and works like a champ.

Kevin Lu is incorrect. Permissions in Azure DevOps work as follows:

Allow: Grant access unless explicitly denied
Deny: Do not allow access under any circumstances, even if Allow is set
Not set: Deny if not explicitly allowed

By setting a global "Deny", you are disallowing access under all circumstances. Use "Not set" instead.
